# Off-by-one bug in reputation graph legend

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-history

On the user's profile page there is the "reputation" tab which shows a chart with all reputation changes. Selecting a smaller area on this chart shows the selection in more detail in a second chart above. Clicking bars on this chart should display the reputation changes a text in a list below the charts.

However, a click on a bar only shows the reputation changes to the bar left to it (if there is one). So it seems there is an off-by-one error for calculating this reputation change list.

See the screenshot for more details. The highlighted bar(40 rep) does not match the legend below (10 rep), but the bar to the left of the highlighted one (10 rep) does.

[image: Screenshot illustrating bug]

Comment: Is this still the case, one hour later? (I think this is due to timezones, but would like confirmation - I, in the UK, can't reproduce at this time)

Comment: I'm in Iran and can reproduce it.

Comment: And now, I can see it too...

Comment: Yes, still the case (4 hours later). I'm in CE(S)T timezone btw. (UTC+02).

Comment: I can still see this bug. Also asked a [question (now deleted)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302769/1860929) about it, before realizing it was a duplicate of this.

Comment: Corresponding report on meta.SE: [Reputation for graph is off by a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259692/reputation-for-graph-is-off-by-a-day)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Timezone shenanigans are always fun.

We recently made a change here to address some other inconsistencies in the graph, but which caused timezones to be considered when they shouldn't.

This is fixed in the next build.

Comment: When's it coming out? Its still [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259692/reputation-for-graph-is-off-by-a-day)

Comment: @UniKitty - what timezone are you at?

Comment: Singapore time zone which is UTC + 8

Comment: Adn I'm in UTC +1 (BST) and see the error. Which is strange because truff normally works here.

Comment: quick query - is that next build out?  Because I see an off by one (reported [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298312/a-new-off-by-one-error-on-the-reputation-graph)) that is similar but different.  Wondering if the two are related.

Comment: Today (2015-07-27) I still see this bug! Is the the new version still not installed? Do we have some kind of bug-tracking-system where we can follow the state of such issues?

Comment: I still see this bug.

Comment: I can still see this bug. Also asked a [question (now deleted)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302769/1860929) about it, before realizing it was a duplicate of this.

Comment: Problem still persists: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260771/reputation-histogram-shows-rep-changes-for-the-nth-1-day

Comment: I've seen this too, so I've removed the [meta-tag:status-completed] tag from the question.

Comment: This problem still persists.I am not able to see on which questions i got the reputation,for few days it shows me the list but for few there it shows no reputation changes.http://stackoverflow.com/users/1529631/netstarter?tab=reputation&sort=graph

Comment: It's still present for me. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259692/reputation-for-graph-is-off-by-a-day/269642#269642

Comment: It's still there for me and it's annoying. It's off by 1, no matter when I look at it, be it at 14:00 CET or 18:00 CET. I don't think it's just a UTC/Timezone issue, then it would be only off by 1 (summertime) or 2 (wintertime) hours around midnight

Comment: [Yet another report of the bug still being present](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UvMJw.png) 9 months later

Answer (score 6):

#### Not an answer, but

> This is fixed in the next build.
>
> ```
>                                            answered Jun 12 '15 at 13:44
> ```

As we live now more than six month lather...

There are two snaphshot of graph on my rep, with detail on 25 and 26 january 2016.

[image: rep on 25 january 2016]

where for *`rep: 75`* I sumarize only *`+10`*, and next day:

[image]

where for *`rep: 18`* I sumarize *`+75`*.

Ok, It's not hawmful, but as StackOverflow could become referencial for programming, that's not so well!

... Sorry!

Nota: My timezone is UTC+1 as wintertime.

```
date +%z
+0100
```

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue as of April 2016, also note that the clickbox is also off few pixels.

[image: bars are fun]

CEST, UTC+2