# A new (?) off-by-one error on the reputation graph

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-history

***Disclaimer up front*** - this question is related to [off-by-one bug in reputation graph legend](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296743/off-by-one-bug-in-reputation-graph-legend), but not exactly the same.  At a guess, it may even be to do with the fix that [Oded describes in that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296775/838992).

Basically - when viewing the reputation graph, the bars are correctly aligned with the dates on the axes, but the tooltip shows the incorrect date (off-by-one) and the details show the reputation for the date in the tooltip, not the date of the bar you click.

#### Example:

In this example, I had 225 rep for today (1st July).  That's a lot for me - so I went to have a look how it compared.  I saw the bar, correctly aligned on July 1st.  However, the tooltip is labelled `June 30,2015` and the details below the graph are also for June 30th.

[image: Screenshot showing the problem]

For reference - I am in the BST / UTC+1 timezone and it's 11am, so I don't think this is a bug around when the UTC day changes.  Obviously I've tried cache clearing, refreshing the page etc.

---

#### Update

[@Vesper](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1627055/vesper) pointed out [in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298312/a-new-off-by-one-error-on-the-reputation-graph?noredirect=1#comment215242_298312) that this particular day might have been affected by the leap second.  I don't think that's the issue, though because I observe it for different days and I think I've seen the behaviour before, although I dismissed it as my misreading at the time.

[image: 22_june_example]

Comment: Maybe this bug refers to recent addition of one second to UTC, that is, the `(Jun 30 00:00:00)+86400` is `Jun 30 23:59:60` and truncated to Jun 30.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so @Vesper - it occurs for different days. Fair thought, though. I think I observed it about 4 days ago, too - although I dismissed it as a caching issue at the time.  If I get time, I'll add another example picture.

Comment: [Reported on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259692/reputation-for-graph-is-off-by-a-day)

Comment: @nicael You're right - this is the same issue. Not sure the screenshots there are as clear on the issue though (i.e. that the bar and the rep in the tooltip correspond to the correct day, but the tooltip date and details are one day off). Kudos for finding it on MSE, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed my fixed to fix this.

Hopefully it is fixed. For good.

Comment: So, who will fix the fixer's fix so it stays fixed?

Comment: All working for me - thanks @Oded :)