# Select date on reputation tab and get changes from day before

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-graph, reputation-tab

On the reputation tab you can select a day. But if I select a day, I get the grand reputations of the day before the selected day.

**For example:** I select 5 december, but I get the grains changes of the 4<sup>th</sup>.

I use Google chrome version 47.0.2526.73 m on Windows 10. Same problem on Firefox version 42.0 and Microsoft Edge version 20.10240.16384.0 also on Windows 10.

Is that normal or is it bug from Stack Overflow?

[image]

Comment: I'm not having the same problem - even your profile. If I had to guess, I'd say you were working off some old javascript and you need to hard refresh your browser.

Comment: I agree with @worldofjr, it's working fine for me. Can you confirm which browser you are using?

Comment: I can confirm on Firefox 42.0 in Windows 8.1. I noticed this more than 6 months ago, but was too lazy to create a bug report. To be honest I don't think this will be fixed as very few bugs that are found in old features are fixed.

Comment: @ArtjomB.: I've try it also on Firefox 42.0 and Google Chrome 47.0.2526.73 m on Windows 10, where I have that problem I've explained.

Comment: @worldofjr: I use Firefox 42.0 and Google Chrome 47.0.2526.73 m on Windows 10

Comment: I am also getting this too but it seems to be erratic. It doesn't always happen, so you should test it with a few different date ranges. Chrome 47.0.2526.73 m on Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: This comes up time and again, see [here.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298312/a-new-off-by-one-error-on-the-reputation-graph) That's the one most use as a dupe target, check the "Linked" section to the side. Though it does look to be more intermittent now. (Which is why I have not actually flagged as dupe here.)