# Bug in Reputation Graph

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page, reputation-graph

**Issue:** Incorrect mapping between reputation graph and posts from which user earned the corresponding reputation

**Detail:**
Bars shown in Reputation graph have incorrect mapping with Post from which reputation has been earned.

for more details look at these attached images:

[image]
**Here reputation earned is 75 but No posts are displayed corresponding to the above bar graphs.**

Now have a look at the image below:

[image]

Again 3 posts are displayed for rep gain of 10 points.

So it seems mapping has been shifted by one day. Or is it timezone dependent.

Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Check this out [Off-by-one bug in reputation graph legend](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296743)