# Off-by-one error in rendering break down of reputation

Tags: bug

I clicked on the 1st April which is a day where I earnt 42 reputation and it showed the correct breakdown of that day but rendered the bar graph as if it was the next day.

[image: Screen shot of off-by-one error on reputation graph view]

It maybe related to [this bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296743/off-by-one-bug-in-reputation-graph-legend) but it appears like it might be different.  The other bug is showing the day (Jan 31st) in the correct position on the graph but the breakdown of the wrong day (Jan 30th). In the case above it's showing the wrong day (correctly drawing the 2nd April value but reporting the 1st April) on the graph, but the breakdown of that day is correct (according to the day label on the graph, and incorrect according to the position of the day on the graph).

Comment: Maybe related but it's different @DavidPostill . There it's showing Jan 31st in the correct position on the graph but showing the breakdown of the wrong day (Jan 30th).  In the case above it's showing the wrong day (correctly drawing the 2nd April value but reporting the 1st April) on the graph, but the breakdown of that day is correct.

Comment: It does however match this one [Reputation for graph is off by a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259692) (which is mentioned as a comment in the proposed dupe as proof it was incorrectly fixed. As a result the status-completed tag was removed from the proposed dupe.

Comment: "1st April which is a day where I earnt 42 reputation" Seriously? That... wow.

Comment: Great.  As long as you're happy it's been reported correctly @DavidPostill :)  Thanks for finding the duplicate(s).