# Reputation per day bar chart index mismatch?

Tags: bug

It seems to me that when I click on a green bar on the chart of the reputation graph then the following three events are triggered:

1. the color of the bar changes to grey, indicating that it is selected; and
2. a tooltip pops up stating the day and the change of reputation; and
3. the corresponding daily activities are described on the bottom of the screen.

However, it seems to me that the height of the bars and the tooltip they show are *not* the same as what is described in the bottom of the screen. Indeed, in the bottom of the screen the daily activities of the *preceding* day's are shown.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that there's a bug here. But you're completely wrong about when and why it happens.

I am unable to reproduce the bug by simply looking at your bar graph and clicking something.

But <kbd>Shift</kbd> clicking on the other hand produces this:

[image]

You'll notice that results are for Aril 15<sup>th</sup>, while the bar selected is for April 26<sup>th</sup>.

The process to replicate this is click on the 26<sup>th</sup>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> click twice on the 15<sup>th</sup>.

Comment: Yes, I guess we live in different time zones. This seems to be a recurring bug: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296743/off-by-one-bug-in-reputation-graph-legend How difficult can be to fix something like this...? The tooltips are at least displayed correctly.

Comment: @Matsmath The thing I brought up is not related to timezones. The days of the bar and the list are 16 days apart.